# how to represent a plane in cavalier perspective?

Tags: html, css

In our Sphinx theme, we are trying to use different colors to represent depth in our dark theme. As users get a bit confused I would like to document the names of these colors and show how they are used in a diagram.

I thought an image would be sufficient but it doesn't really fit the font used and/or the colors are not rendered precisely the same.

[image]

Does anyone know how to reproduce this figure using pure css + html ?
I tried using transform3d but I only manage to get isometric perspective `transform: rotateX(60deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(-45deg);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this solution with two transforms `transform:skew(); transform:translate()`. I've created some classes to make it easy customize and using `style="--order: 0"` to select the levels.

```css
*,
::after,
::before {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  line-height: 1;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
}

html,
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  min-width: 100vw;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}

.container {
  --width: 400px;
  --height: 120px;
  width: var(--width);
  height: var(--height);
  position: relative;
}

.color-100 {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.color-200 {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
}

.color-300 {
  background-color: #ffffee;
}

.plain {
  position: absolute;
  border: 2px solid #dfdfdf;
}

.full-width {
  width: var(--width);
  transform: skew(-45deg);
}

.full-height {
  height: var(--height);
}

.half-width {
  width: calc(var(--width) / 2);
  transform: skew(-45deg) translate(calc(-2rem * var(--order)), calc(-2rem * var(--order)));
  z-index: var(--order);
}

.third-width {
  width: calc(var(--width) / 3);
  transform: skew(-45deg) translate(calc(-2rem * var(--order)), calc(-2rem * var(--order)));
  z-index: var(--order);
}

.half-height {
  height: calc(var(--height) * 0.5);
  transform: skew(-45deg) translate(-1.5rem, calc(-2rem * var(--order)));
  z-index: var(--order);
}

.two-thirds-height {
  height: calc(var(--height) * 0.66);
  transform: skew(-45deg) translate(-2.5rem, calc(-2rem * var(--order)));
  z-index: var(--order);
}

.right {
  right: 0;
}

.label {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0.5rem;
  left: 50%;
  transform: skew(45deg) translateX(-50%);
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<main class="container">
  <div class="plain full-width full-height color-100" style="--order: 0">
    <p class="label">background</p>
  </div>
  <div class="plain third-width full-height color-100" style="--order: 1">
    <p class="label">on-background</p>
  </div>
  <div class="plain third-width full-height right color-200" style="--order: 1">
    <p class="label">surface</p>
  </div>
  <div class="plain third-width two-thirds-height right color-300" style="--order: 2">
    <p class="label">on-surface</p>
  </div>
</main>
```